# C++ 11: How to write 2 template functions that differ in their return type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

What I'm trying to do is have two function templates: one that translates a string to an `boost::optional<some integer type>` and one that translates a string to a `boost::optional<some enum type>`. Something like this:

```
template<typename T> boost::optional<T> func(const std::string &s) { return boost::make_optional(std::stoi(s));}
template<typename T> boost::optional<T> func(const std::string &s) { return boost::make_optional(EnumMapper<T>::map_string_to_enum<T>(s));}

enum Color { Red, Blue, Green};
enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right};

auto a = func<int>("1234");
auto b = func<Color>("red");
auto c = func<Direction>("up");
```

I have something working where I make specializations for every enum type:

```
template<> boost::optional<Color> func(const std::string &s) { return boost::make_optional(EnumMapper<Color>::map_string_to_enum<Color>(s));}
template<> boost::optional<Direction> func(const std::string &s) { return boost::make_optional(EnumMapper<Direction>::map_string_to_enum<Direction>(s));}
```

but with literally dozens of enums this seems ugly and error prone. I have a feeling that this is what type traits are there for, but none of the examples I found seems to work for what I want to do.

Edit: Thanks to songyuanyao! This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
};

enum Direction {
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
};

template <typename T> struct EnumMapper { static boost::optional<T> map_string_to_enum(const std::string &s) = delete; };

template <> boost::optional<Color> EnumMapper<Color>::map_string_to_enum(const std::string &s) {
    return Color::Green;
}

template <> boost::optional<Direction> EnumMapper<Direction>::map_string_to_enum(const std::string &s) {
    return Direction::Right;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, boost::optional<T>>::type
func(const std::string &s) { 
    return EnumMapper<T>::map_string_to_enum(s);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, boost::optional<T>>::type
func(const std::string &s) { 
    return boost::make_optional<T>(std::stoi(s));
}

int
main() {
    auto a = func<std::uint8_t>("123");
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(*a) << std::endl;
    auto b = func<Color>("Red");
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(*b) << std::endl;
    auto c = func<Direction>("Up");
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(*c) << std::endl;
    auto d = func<std::uint32_t>("2345");
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(*d) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the type trait `std::is_enum`, and apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, boost::optional<T>>::type
func(const std::string &s) { 
    return boost::make_optional(EnumMapper<T>::map_string_to_enum<T>(s));
}
```

Note that you have to constrain on type for the 1st overload too. You can check whether it's `int`, or use `std::is_integral`. E.g.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, boost::optional<T>>::type
func(const std::string &s) { 
    return boost::make_optional(std::stoi(s));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to make some minor changes for C++ 11.

Comment: @jpo234 Sorry didn't notice the C++11 tag. I fixed my answer.